# Best way to organize text through patterns?

Tags: java, regex

I have scraped a bunch of information, and need to organize it into several fields. The only issue is that there is no specific header before the information to identify it with and create a pattern and matcher. I have included the information for 2 sets of data below. As shown, identifiers are just "left" or "center" showing where they are on the screen. What would be the best way to search and organize each set of data into a CSV, by adding in each field from each data set? The data that would need to be saved would be everything afer "left"> or "center"> to

```
<td align="left">ERIK DAVIDOVIC, ET AL  </td><td align="left">5620 GOODMAN DRIVE</td><td align="center">NORTH ROYALTON</td><td align="center">44133-0000</td><td align="center">
                        <a id="SheetContentPlaceHolder_ctl00_gvForeclosureResutls_lbCaseNum_0" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$SheetContentPlaceHolder$ctl00$gvForeclosureResutls$ctl02$lbCaseNum&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" style="display:inline-block;width:100px;">CV-13-798497</a>
                    </td><td align="center">488-05-029</td><td align="center">I</td><td align="center">01/02/2013</td>
        </tr><tr style="background-color:Gainsboro;">


            <td align="left">UNKNOWN HEIRS, ETC OF D.C. RUFUS, ET AL  </td><td align="left">10603 HAMPDEN AVENUE</td><td align="center">CLEVELAND</td><td align="center">44108-0000</td><td align="center">
                        <a id="SheetContentPlaceHolder_ctl00_gvForeclosureResutls_lbCaseNum_1" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$SheetContentPlaceHolder$ctl00$gvForeclosureResutls$ctl03$lbCaseNum&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" style="display:inline-block;width:100px;">CV-13-798498</a>
                    </td><td align="center">109-16-094</td><td align="center">A</td><td align="center">01/02/2013</td>
        </tr><tr style="background-color:LightGrey;">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a parser like http://jsoup.org/ to parse your html file and extract information using selectors.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

actually, this is a pretty structured looking table.

you should be able to parse on the `<td..>` to know that a new value is beginning, then start a new row on the `<tr>`

you would just count which `<td>` you are on within the row to know which column the value represents.

Comment: What class or classes would I use to do this? Pattern and Matcher? If so, would I need to use several pattern delimiters?

Comment: possibly. you would use one pattern for the <tr></tr> pairs - that = one row, then inside that loop, use another pattern for the <td> sets